# Setting layout in Android activity crashes application

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am developing an android application using OpenCV. In my camera activity, when I am setting layout, application crashes.
I dont know why my application is behaving abnormally. It crashes randomly.First there was error when instantiated ScanCameraPreview, but now, it crashes while setting layout.

**CameraActivity.java**

```
public CameraActivity() 
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);   // Crashes here

    mOpenCvCameraView = (ScanCameraPreview) findViewById(R.id.camera_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    //mOpenCvCameraView.setCameraRotation();
    ......
}
```

This is my layout

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/camera_activity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CameraActivity" >


<com.example.androiddms.ScanCameraPreview
    android:id="@+id/camera_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my custom camera view

```
public class ScanCameraPreview extends JavaCameraView 
{
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidDms::ScanCameraView";

    public ScanCameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.d(this.toString(), "Starting camera preview");
        //mCamera.getParameters().get
    }
}
```

Please help me. I debugged it carefully pointwise and it crashes at setcontentview.
Thanks for your time.

Here it is my logcat[image]

Comment: @Nambi saying "post your question properly" is not what you're supposed to say in the *edit summary*. It's a useless comment and offensive.

Comment: Please dont downvote without comment, atleast I can learn to improve my question,

Comment: @Anamika, I posted my logcat as well

Comment: @MukeshSharma dont post the `screen shot` copy ur err log nd paste it

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding all three constructors for ScanCameraPreview

```
public class ScanCameraPreview extends JavaCameraView 
{
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidDms::ScanCameraView";

    public ScanCameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        Log.d(this.toString(), "Starting camera preview");
        //mCamera.getParameters().get
    }

    public ScanCameraPreview(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        Log.d(this.toString(), "Starting camera preview");
        //mCamera.getParameters().get
    }


    public ScanCameraPreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int style) 
    {
        super(context, attrs,style);
        Log.d(this.toString(), "Starting camera preview");
        //mCamera.getParameters().get
    }
}
```